# Oracle Database and .NET: no constraint warning when trying to add duplicate key field data that are uncommitted deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, oracle11g

**Greetings!
 I have a question regarding .NET and Oracle.**

Lets say I have a database table  with 3 columnfields, ID, Name and Email where ID is unique.

If I manually add, delete and add the same data directly to the database using a thirdpart datatool, such as Toad, everything works fine.

The problem however occurs when I start doing the same through .NET, with entity frameworks for example, in combination with Toad.

**Scenario and result of the problem in question:**
I fire up .NET  and using C# with entity frameworks I successfully test and add a new row to the database table for all 3 columnfields with the following data:
ID:1
Name:"Bert"
Email:"example@something.com"

Since the data for each column is hardcoded in the test I'm working on I delete the data from the database table using Toad so I can use the same ID while doing the test in .NET; In Toad I select the
row in the table to be deleted, I then press the delete button (marked with the "-" sign). The row vanishes in Toad, I press the refresh table button and it's gone.

When I try to add a new row however, using the same data again .NET simply starts running the code and then nothing happens, I don't get a warning or anything, it just keeps doing like its in a constant loop until I cancel the code execution.

So, what I do is that I, after some fiddling, find out that I have to hit "commit" in order for the changes to actually "happen" which basically solves the entire problem.

**So what is my question then?**
Why won't I get an error regarding a field constraint or some kind of error at all? It's obvious that the data somehow is still lurking around the database after the delete and that I have to commit the changes before adding the same data all over again, why does the .NET code just start going into a loop instead of giving out errors?

is this "working as intended" or is it a some kind of bug where a error is suppose to be generated but it gets lost somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .NET session is waiting for the resource which is locked by your TOAD session. In order to provide unique constraint checks in a concurrent environment Oracle uses some internal locks when you're performing DML on the unique column(s). It's not a row-level lock and not a table-level lock.  It is a lock on the Unique Key constraint. For example:

```
create table t1 (id number primary key);

--session 1
insert into t1 values(1);
-- no commit;

--session 2
insert into t1 values(2);
commit;
-- no problem;

-- session 3
insert into t1 values(1);
-- waiting
```

In the above example Oracle is locking the rows which contain id = 1 because Session1 is performing DML with id = 1 and id is primary (and unique) key.

Here is also some info: http://technology.amis.nl/2013/02/28/how-oracle-database-uses-internal-locks-to-make-statement-level-constraint-validation-robust-at-the-transaction-level/